# Can I get the URL a RequireJS dependecy maps to?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Can I get the URL a RequireJS dependecy maps to?

```
var foo = require('my-dependency');
```

I know my-dependency is being pulled from `http://localhost/version/my-dependency.js`. Does RequireJS expose an API to get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`require.toUrl("my-dependency")`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes) to get a URL that is *relative* to your current module. For instance, this should output a relative URL:

```
define(function (require) {
  console.log(require.toUrl("my-dependency"));
});
```

You need to use the local `require` for this so that RequireJS knows what module it is being called from. (There's no need for a dependency list above. If you do not pass a list, RequireJS uses a dependency list of ["require", "module", "exports"].)

I don't know of a single-step way to get an absolute URL but if you need an absolute URL you could combine the URL provided by `module.uri` with the return value of `require.toUrl`:

```
define(function (require, module) {
  console.log(join(module.uri, require.toUrl("my-dependency")));
});
```

(`join` is a function that is capable of joining URLs. You can use [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/), some other library, or write your own.)